# nlp- Difference between Sentences and a Document in Stanford OpenNLP?

Tags: nlp, opennlp, stanford-nlp

Let us say we have an article that we want to annotate. If we input the text as one really long Sentence as opposed to a Document, does Stanford do anything differently between annotating that one long Sentence as opposed to looping through every Sentence in the Document and culminating all of its results together?

EDIT: I ran a test and it seems like the two approaches return two different NER sets. I might be just doing it wrong, but it's certainly super interesting and I'm curious as to why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm: you mean Stanford CoreNLP (as opposed to Apache OpenNLP), right?

The main difference in the CoreNLP Simple API between a `Sentence` and a `Document` is tokenization. A `Sentence` will force the entire text to be considered as a single sentence, even if it has punctuation. A `Document` will first tokenize the text into a list of sentences, and then annotate each sentence.

Note that for annotators like the constituency parser, very long sentences will take prohibitively long to annotate. Also, note that coreference only works on documents, not sentences.

Comment: Right, I mean Stanford's version. And that is what I suspected. Given the differing interpretations, the algorithms must treat them differently semantically, which probably explains the differing results.

Comment: how can one use the document in the regular (or interactive) coreNLP system? is it sufficient to run all the sentences in one superlong line to force coreference analysis?

Comment: By default, corenlp treats every file you annotate as a document. I believe each line in the interactive console is also treated as a document.